# Unique Together key validation error in Django admin inline forms

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have following structure of models A, B and C.

```
class A(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=40)
    ...
    ...


class B(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    a = models.OneToOneField(A, verbose_name=_('A'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class C(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, verbose_name=_('A'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B, verbose_name=_('A'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(_('Name'), max_length=40)
    number = models.IntegerField(_('Number'))
    created = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        class Meta:
        unique_together = ('b', 'name', 'number')
```

Following is code for Model form and Tabular inline admin of class C.

```
class CForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = C
        exclude = ['created',]
        widgets = {
            'b': forms.HiddenInput,
        }

class CInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = C
    form = CForm
    classes = ['collapse']
    fields = ('name', 'number', 'b', )
    readonly_fields = ('created', )
    extra = 0

    def has_delete_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return False
```

After that I have registered CInline class as a inline in Admin of Model A as shown in below code.

```
class AAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [B, CInline]
```

I am able to see inline section in admin screen of model A and save it, but when I open it for change and click on save button with/without any changes in field it raises validation error `C with this name, number and b already exists.`

I don't have any idea why it is raising validation error in change form even we didn't change any fields.

If I remove CInline from inlines then it is working as expected.

How to handle this kind of situation?

Comment: What is the value of `C.name` when you try to submit the form?

Comment: It's a same value which was populated from database in update form.

Comment: Yes - I am asking what that value is? Is it an empty string?

Comment: No its not an empty string. It has name value.

Comment: And you are sure that there is no other entity in the database with the same values of `name`, `number` and `b`?

Comment: Yes I am sure about that. In database table of class C there's no other entity with same value of `name`, `number` and `b` as we have unique constraint on database level.

Comment: Is there any issue with foreign keys? In Admin page for `Class A` there is inline section of `Class B` has foreign key of  `Class A` but other inline section of `Class C` has foreign key of both `Class A` and `Class B`.
If i remove `Class C` from inline then it works fine.

Comment: One more thing I have set column `a` and `b` in inline section as hidden field as I don't want to display it in front-end.